# CGPathRef as a parameter of bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath method

Tags: sprite-kit, structure, skphysicsbody

I am trying to do something like this:

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

CGPathMoveToPoint(path,nil,0,0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil,0, 500);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil,700,500);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil,700,0);
border = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath:path];
```

But method bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath taking the argument of CGPathRef which is defined like this:

```
typedef **const** struct CGPath *CGPathRef;
```

and CGMutablePathRef is declared like this:

```
typedef struct CGPath *CGMutablePathRef;
```

and still is possible to pass CGMutablePathRef to bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath method without compiler errors.

What is the proper way to use this method and which type of struct should be passed as a parameter?

Comment: you're doing it right, except that you have to CGPathRelease(path) after creating the body

Comment: I did that in the code :) but not in this example, thank you. Can I ask one more thing...How to add multiple paths to the scene ? Because right now my scene.physicsBody = border.Should I make a node for new physics edge and then just add it to the scene like any node else?